# Why did the Bavli form of weekly Torah reading become the standard?

Tags: history, torah-reading

My understanding of the Torah reading cycle - In Israel, they originally had a triennial cycle, and in Bavel, they had an annual cycle.

At some point, the Bavli (annual) cycle became the standard. (The triennial cycle that is used, currently, in many Conservative and Reform synagogues is not the same as the original triennial cycle.) At what point and why was that change made?

Comment: Probably because Simchas Torah is fun!  More seriously, finishing a big chunk always generates more excitement towards learning.  I overheard someone who's given Daf Yomi shiurim for several cycles mention that the end of Bava Basra is always really hard for him.

Comment: @Heshy " finishing a big chunk always generates more excitement towards learning". I'm not sure if you can compare Torah to "Daf Yomi". It becomes a balance of speed vs. quality. If you wanted the excitement over finishing Sha"s, Agudah might have, then, suggested learning a whole *Masechta* each day, and you could have a siyum every day.

Comment: Why do we learn Bavli more compared to Yerushalmi?

Comment: Right, but as you said it depends on the quality.  A 3 year cycle would be more conducive to learning Malbim (speaking from experience here - a few years ago I tried this, barely made it through Mishpatim, fell behind during Vayikra, and didn't catch up until Ki Tavo) or Or Hachayim, for instance.  But maybe they felt people were just doing Rashi anyway, so it was worth speeding up and the quality wouldn't suffer too much.  (I'm being anachronistic, Rashi probably wasn't born yet, but you get the idea.)

Comment: Most Babylonian customs prevailed over the competing Israeli ones. The Israeli community was devastated during the crusades and eventually essentially died out.

Comment: relevant background reading: https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-fox-on-parsha/cycles_of_renewal/

Comment: Those are **not the only practiced, they are the only mentioned**. When learning the Sugia, I got the conclusion that **Moses' original decree to read the Torah weekly was not consequential, but freestyle** according to the community Rabbi's decision with portions relevant to different occasions and festivals. That held practically till Ezrah times, then a need for unification arose.

Comment: @AlBerko Where do you see that Moshe had a decree to read it weekly? The Gemara (Megillah 31a) just says that he decreed that we read a portion relating to each holiday on the relevant holiday. It wasn’t until Ezra that we read it weekly.

Answer (score 5):

### When did it become the standard?

This type of question can often not be answered so precisely. Somewhat of an estimate can be made based on a statement of [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides):

**[Hilchot Tefila 13:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=7&perek=13&hilite=)**

> המנהג הפשוט בכל ישראל שמשלימין את התורה בשנה אחת מתחילין בשבת שאחר חג
>   הסוכות וקורין בסדר בראשית בשניה אלה תולדות בשלישית ויאמר יי' אל אברם
>   וקוראין והולכין על הסדר הזה עד שגומרין את התורה בחג הסוכות ויש מי
>   שמשלים את התורה בשלש שנים ואינו מנהג פשוט
>
> The common custom throughout all Israel is to complete the [reading
>   of] the Torah in one year. [The cycle] is begun on the Sabbath after
>   the Sukkot festival, reading the sidrah, Bereshit. On the following
>   Sabbath, [the sidrah,] Eleh toldot [is read]; on the third, [the
>   sidrah,] Vayomer Ado-nai el Avram. We continue reading according to
>   this order until the Torah is completed, during the Sukkot festival.
>
> There are those who finish the Torah reading in a three-year cycle.
>   However, this is not a widely accepted custom. ([Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920178/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Thirteen.htm))

Assuming that Rambam is giving us an accurate description, we can say that by the Twelfth Century the triennial cycle had been virtually eradicated.

### Why did it become the standard?

This also involves a bit of guesswork. The following theory is based mostly on the commentary of R. Yissachar Tamar to Yerushalmi Megillah 4:1, reproduced below with key parts bolded.

The Talmud tells us of a decree promulgated by Ezra:

**[Megillah 31b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=31b&format=pdf)**

> תניא ר' שמעון בן אלעזר אומר עזרא תיקן להן לישראל שיהו קורין קללות
>   שבתורת כהנים קודם עצרת ושבמשנה תורה קודם ר"ה מאי טעמא אמר אביי ואיתימא
>   ריש לקיש כדי שתכלה השנה וקללותיה בשלמא שבמשנה תורה איכא כדי שתכלה שנה
>   וקללותיה אלא שבתורת כהנים אטו עצרת ראש השנה היא אין עצרת נמי ראש השנה
>   היא דתנן ובעצרת על פירות האילן
>
> It has been taught: R. Simeon b. Eleazar says: Ezra made a regulation
>   for Israel that they should read the curses in Leviticus before
>   Pentecost and those in Deuteronomy before New Year. What is the
>   reason? — Abaye — or you may also say Resh Lakish said: So that the
>   year may end along with its curses. I grant you that in regard to the
>   curses in Deuteronomy you can say, ‘so that the year should end along
>   with its curses’. But as regards those In Leviticus — is Pentecost a
>   New Year? — Yes; Pentecost is also a New Year, as we have learnt: ‘On
>   Pentecost is the new year for [fruit of] the tree’. ([Soncino
>   translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Megilah.pdf))

In order to read these sections before Shavuot and Rosh Hashanah (without skipping) one must of necessity complete the entire Torah every year. How then could there have been a triennial cycle, if that would fly in the face of Ezra's decree?

This question is in fact asked by [R. Yaakov Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden), and he has no answer:

> אלא מיהא הא קשיא לי טובא דהאמרינן שילהי מכילתין עזרא תקן שיהו קורין
>   קללות שבת"כ לפני עצרת ושל משנה תורה לפני ר"ה וכה"ג [דמנהג בני מערבא]
>   מי מתרמי להו

This is similarly pointed out by [R. Tzvi Hirsch Chajes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zvi_Hirsch_Chajes), who likewise has no answer:

> נ"ב לפ"ז לא ידעתי לבני מערבא דמסקי אורייתא בתלת שנין עי' לעיל כ"ט ע"ב
>   איך היו עושים בתקנת עזרא זאת שתבא  קריאת הקללות קודם עצרת בכל שנה

However, it is possible that Ezra's decree never fully took hold in all of Israel, because it was too much for the people to bear, just like we find regarding his decree requiring immersion after a seminal emission. The reason why it would have been to hard to bear was that the Torah was read with a verse-by-verse Aramaic translation. In order to complete the entire Torah in one year with the verse-by-verse translation, many hours of Synagogue services would be necessary. that was simply too much for the people, so they only completed 1/3 of the Torah each year.

However, the practice of reading the Torah with the verse-by-verse translation eventually died out. Already in the ~Twelfth Century Tosafot states that this was no longer the custom.

**[Megillah 23b s.v. Lo](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=23b&format=pdf)**

> ועל זה אנו סומכין שאין אנו מתרגמין הפטרות שבכל ימות השנה וכן הפרשיות

As the communities ceased reading the translations, they no longer had to worry about the services taking many hours, so there was no longer any reason to not accept Ezra's decree of completing the entire Torah every year.

**Alei Tamar Yerushalmi Megillah 4:1**

> והנה הרמב"ם הלכות תפלה פי"ג ה"א כתב המנהג הפשוט בכל ישראל שמשלימים את
>   התורה בשנה אחת ומבואר כן בבבלי סוף מגילה אולם לא ידע ממתי החל המנהג
>   הזה אכן במגילה ל"א ע"ב תניא רשב"א אומר עזרא תקן להם לישראל שיהיו קורין
>   קללות שבתו"כ קודם עצרת ושבמשנה תורה קודם ר"ה הרי שכבר בימי עזרא היו
>   משלימים את התורה בשנה אחת אולם בהגהות יעב"ץ בדף כ"ט תמה על הא דאמרינן
>   שם בני מערבא מסקי לדאוריתא בתלת שנין דהא אמרינן דעזרא תיקן שיהיו קורין
>   קללות שבתו"כ לפני עצרת ושל משנה תורה לפני ר"ה וכה"ג מי מתרמי להו וש"מ
>   שמשלימים התורה בשנה אחת ולא מצא מענה **ולפענ"ד שתקנת עזרא בזה לא פשטה
>   בא"י כמו שטבילת עזרא לא פשטה בכל ישראל ולא היה בכח הציבור לעמוד בה
>   כמ"ש ברמב"ם הלכות תפלה פ"ד ה"ה וכ"ה ביומא פ"א ה"א עיי"ש ואף כאן מפני
>   שהאריכו בתרגום התורה בדרשות בא"י כמ"ש בתרגום יב"ע לא היה בכחן להשלים
>   את פרשת השבוע בכל שבוע מפני טורח הציבור שהיו צריכים לשהות שעות הרבה
>   ומפני כן גמרו התורה בשלש שנים** וכן משמע מהרמב"ם שם שבה"א כתב ויש
>   שמשלימים את התורה בשלש שנים ובה"ב הביא תקנת עזרא נגד מנהג זה א"ו שאין
>   כאן קושיא מפני שלא פשטה ולא עוד אלא אפילו בבבל גופא לא פשטה תקנת עזרא
>   זו כמו התקנה שאין קורין קללות שבתו"כ בשבת שלפני עצרת אלא בשני שבתות
>   שלפניה וז"ל הרמב"ם שם ה"ב עזרא תיקן להם לישראל שיהיו קורין קללות שבספר
>   ויקרא קודם עצרת ושבמשנה תורה קודם ר"ה והמנהג הפשוט שיהיו קורין במדבר
>   סיני קודם עצרת אתם ניצבים קודם ר"ה עכ"ל ונראה שרוצה להעיר ע"ז שהמנהג
>   אינו כתקנת עזרא שלפי תקנת עזרא היו צריכים לקרות בחוקותי קודם עצרת וכי
>   תבא קודם ר"ה ברם המנהג אינו כן שקורין במדבר סיני לפני עצרת ואתם ניצבים
>   קודם ר"ה והקללות שבתו"כ קורין שתי שבתות שלפני עצרת ושל משנה תורה שתי
>   שבתות לפני ר"ה ונראה שטעם המנהג הוא שלא רצו להסמיך הקללות למתן תורה
>   ולר"ה ובב"ב פ"ב בין עשר תקנות שתקן עזרא נזכרת טבילה לבעל קרי ואלו תקנה
>   זו לא נזכרה כלל ומפני שלא פשטה בכל ישראל אף במקום שפשטה לא פשטה כתקנתה
>   אולם בהג"מ שם לא כתב כן עיי"ש

Comment: There's no reason to think Ezra's enactment was as part of an annual cycle. Zakhor is read before Purim every year even in a triennial cycle

Comment: @DoubleAA Not necessarily – Sefer Hachinuch #603: ודי לנו בזה לזכור הענין פעם אחת בשנה או שתי שנים ושלש והנה בכל מקומות ישראל קוראים ספר התורה בשנה אחת או בשתים או שלש לכל הפחות והנה הם יוצאים בכך מצוה זו. Also, the Alei Tamar argued that the very next halacha in the Rambam support this understanding of Ezra's enactment.

Comment: yes necessarily. The 4 Parshiyot is a Mishna! (Btw one of the suggested reasons for instituting Zakhor before Purim and not relying on Ki Tetze is because of the triennial cycle.)

Comment: What is the source for "Pentecost" (Shavuot) is the new year for fruit of the trees? Does that contradict 1st Mishnah Rosh Hashanah that says that it's on 15 of Shevat?

Comment: @Double AA I edited in the Maharatz Chayes who asks the same question. I also think that's the clear pashtus of the Gemara. The Gemara's saying that we want to get the klalos over with before the new year Having a special additional reading right before the new year does not accomplish that; having a yearly cycle does accomplish that. The four parshiot are completely different. It is indeed a Mishnah, but that's clearly telling us to have a special reading for those weeks. It would be impossible to have a cycle that conforms to the four parshiot.

Comment: @DanF The Gemara is quoting the Mishnah from Rosh Hashana 16a which says: בארבעה פרקים העולם נידון בפסח על התבואה בעצרת על פירות האילן

Comment: Rosh Megilah 3:6 says even in times of the Gemara not all used translations